# What makes something relevant to an argument, and how can one assess relevance?

Tags: argumentation, semantics

Are there any books that examine questions about relevance in general like the following?
[Relevance Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_theory) seems something else and inapplicable.

1. What makes something (ir)relevant to an argument or discourse?
2. How can humans improve on deciding whether something is (ir)relevant?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of argumentation relevance falls under the subject area of informal logic. The canonical reference is Johnson and Blair's [Logical Self-defense](https://books.google.com/books?id=ojNbr4vYooQC&source=gbs_navlinks_s). According to the summary in [SEP's Informal Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-informal/#Ded):

> "*Following Johnson & Blair (1977, 1994) many informal logicians understand informal validity in terms of relevance and sufficiency, making the criteria for good argument acceptability, relevance and sufficiency (the “ARS” criteria). The premises of an argument count as relevant to its conclusion when they provide some support for the conclusion and sufficient when they provide enough support to establish it as plausible. Relevance can be contrasted with irrelevance, which occurs in various instances of non sequitor, as occurs in the case of “straw man” and “red herring” arguments, which are common in ordinary discourse.*"

Another aspect that should be mentioned is the [relevance logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance). The idea is that the usual material conditional, which validates inferences like "if the Moon is made of cheese then the Riemann hypothesis is false", is too permissive and counterintuitive. The idea is that conclusions should be inferred only if the premises are relevant to the them, this leads to introducing the relevant conditional. There is a bit of a tension in trying to formalize a notion which is based on conceptual content rather than form:

> "*But there is a formal principle that relevant logicians apply to force theorems and inferences to “stay on topic”. This is the variable sharing principle. The variable sharing principle says that no formula of the form A → B can be proven in a relevance logic if A and B do not have at least one propositional variable (sometimes called a proposition letter) in common and that no inference can be shown valid if the premises and conclusion do not share at least one propositional variable... As we shall see, however, relevant logic does provide us with a relevant notion of proof in terms of the real use of premises, but it does not by itself tell us what counts as a true (and relevant) implication. It is only when the formal theory is put together with a philosophical interpretation that it can do this.*"

Relevance logics are even used to block the destructive effects of contradictions in classical reasoning, with the relevant conditional the law of explosion is no longer valid, contradiction does not imply anything. In other words, [relevance logics are paraconsistent](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-paraconsistent/#RelLog).

Finally, [Wikipedia's Relevance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance) also has some relevant (pardon the pun) references, for example [Sperber-Wilson's Precis of  Relevance: Communication and Cognition](http://www.dan.sperber.fr/wp-content/uploads/Pr%C3%A9cis-of-Relevance-Communication-and-Cognition.pdf), which looks at the cognitive side of it:

> "*Grice's idea that the very act of communicating creates expectations  which  it  then  exploits  provides  a  starting point.  Beyond  that,  the  inferential  model  needs  radical reworking  in  order  to  become  truly  explanatory.  A psychologically  realistic answer  must  be  given  to  such  basic questions as these: What  shared  information  is exploited in  communication?  What  forms  of  inference  are  used? What is relevance and how is it achieved? What role does the  search  for  relevance  play  in  communication?*
>
> [...] *It  should be clear  that  we  are  not  trying  to  define  the  ordinary  and rather   fuzzy   English   word    relevance.   We   believe, though, that there is an important psychological property -   a property  involved  in  mental  processes  -  which  the ordinary  notion  of  relevance   roughly  approximates,  and which  it  is  therefore  appropriate  to  call  by  that  name, using  it  in  a  technical  sense...  We then define:*
>
> ***Extent  condition  1:*** An assumption  is relevant  in a context  to
>   the  extent  that  its  contextual  effects  in  that  context  are large.
>
> ***Extent  condition  2:*** An assumption  is relevant  in a context  to
>   the extent that the effort  required  to process it in that context is
>   small."

Answer (score 0):

In law, these questions about relevance are the subject of a lot of practical and theoretical thinking. Here is Federal Rule of Evidence 401, Test for Relevant Evidence:

> Evidence is relevant if:
>
> (a) it has any tendency to make a fact more or less probable than it
>   would be without the evidence; and
>
> (b) the fact is of consequence in determining the action.

That brief desciption is supported by thoughtful commentary. *See* Notes of Advisory Committee. https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/fre/rule_401 The Notes are accessible to a nonlawyer.

As for improvement, the question of relevance is always being examined and refined All of Article IV, Rules 401-415 dealing in varying degrees of detail with the question of relevance.